# Concatenate DATEADD & DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Server 2008.
Is there a way to concatenate the below and drop  the `00:00:00:000`?

*Edit - fulldate column contains a list of dates

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, fulldate)-1), fulldate) [WeekStart], 
    DATEADD(dd, 7-    (DATEPART(dw, fulldate)), fulldate) [WeekEnd]
FROM time
WHERE YEAR(time) >= 2016
ORDER BY WeekStart
```

Results:

WeekOf

```
12-27-2015-01-02-2016
```

Etc...

Comment: In SQL Server you cannot `ORDER BY` an alias

Comment: @Serpiton - yes you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dateadd` returns `date` not string - you have to convert your values to strings first using appropriate [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) (110 in your case) and then concatenate them:

```
select distinct
    convert(nvarchar(20), DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, fulldate)-1), fulldate), 110) + '-' + 
    convert(nvarchar(20), DATEADD(dd, 7-    (DATEPART(dw, fulldate)), fulldate), 110) as WeekOf
from time
where YEAR(time) >= 2016
order by WeekStart
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, nvarchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @MrJohn oops, it was a typo in the answer. It should be `convert` instead of `cast` there.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, would it be possible to not return a year and century for the created WeekOf column?

Comment: Figured it out, I just changed lenght type from 20 to 05